# How do I force for new page after every three rows in pdfTable using iTextsharp?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, pdf, itext

The rows are dynamic I want new page after every 3 rows.

I tried

```
 table.SplitLate = false;
```

but It won't work please help me out.

Comment: Simply begin a new table after three rows and call `NewPage` in-between.

Comment: Thanks @mkl it was very helpfull.

Comment: Ok, I made that comment into an actual answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to enforce a page break in a table is to actually create multiple `PdfPTable` objects, a separate one for the content destined for each page, and by turns add one of these objects to the `Document` and call `NewPage`.

In case of the OP's task he should begin a new table after three rows and call `NewPage` in-between adding these table objects.